# Coding swf in order to force running in my site

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I recently have secure https on my site.
So I'd like to update few coding lines in my swf flash games.

Now I have this:

```
path = _url.substring(0,22);
if (path == "http://lnx.sinapsi.org" || path == "http://win.sinapsi.org")
{
play();
}else{
stop();
getURL("http://www.sinapsi.org","_parent");
}
```

But I need adding also the https path, how?
I tried this:

```
path = _url.substring(0,23);
if (path == "https://lnx.sinapsi.org" || path == "https://win.sinapsi.org")
{
play();
}else
path = _url.substring(0,22);
if (path == "http://lnx.sinapsi.org" || path == "http://win.sinapsi.org")
{
play();
}else{
stop();
getURL("http://www.sinapsi.org","_parent");
}
```

But doesn't work :-(

Please, help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [**`substr`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substr()) method instead...

> [**`substr`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#substr())( **startPos**:Number = 0, **length**:Number = 2147483647 max):String
>
> Returns a substring consisting of the characters that start at the
>   specified `startPos` and with a length specified by `length`. The original
>   string is unmodified.

Your code would then have this logic...

```
path = _url.substr(0,23);

if (path == "https://lnx.sinapsi.org" || path == "https://win.sinapsi.org")  { play(); }

else
{
    path = _url.substr(0,22);

    if (path == "http://lnx.sinapsi.org" || path == "http://win.sinapsi.org")  { play(); }
    else { stop(); getURL("http://www.sinapsi.org","_parent"); }
}
```

If all fails, then just check what the heck the compiler sees...

```
path = _url.substr(0,23);
trace("checking Path : " + path);
```

*Disclaimer :* This is an untested suggestion but it might work for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look AS3, more of AS1/AS2. I think that's what you want:

```
// Split url into Array by "/" character and get only domain string.
// That allows you to avoid guessing substr indexes.
domain = _url.split("/")[2];

// Switch looks more neat and elegant than barrage of ifs.
switch (domain)
{
    case "lnx.sinapsi.org":
    case "win.sinapsi.org":
        play();
        break;

    default:
        stop();
        getURL("http://www.sinapsi.org","_top");
        break;
}
```